# Teclas especiales pierden efecto eventualmente (LINUX MINT)

Tags: linux, hardware

soy nuevo en linux, tengo dual boot (linux mint windows 10) y tengo un problema latente. Sucede que si dejo presionadas las teclas como ctrl, fn, shift etc. hacen su función pero sólo los primero segundos, es decir. Si presiono shift+tecla con el número 3
###############3333333333333333
Primero obtengo el caracter especial de gato y luego vuelvo a obtener el tres. Ya intenté configurar el retraso y repetición de las teclas pero el problema persiste.
Lo que más me hace ruido es que por momentos funciona muy bien y todo el tiempo que tenga presionada la "tecla especial" hace su función.
Alguna idea de qué esté pasando?

Comment: Solo por probar, comprueba si te pasa lo mismo con otro teclado.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.